rstudio variable autocomplete for custom function argument after supplying a dataset
Rstudio has really useful code autocompletions particularly when referencing variables in a dataset (data.frame/tibble). To achieve this, we use a pipe operator (%>%/|>) e.g.,
library(tidyverse)
mtcars %>% 
  group_by()


ggplot2 now also achieves this without needing to include the pipe operator directly, see here:
ggplot(data = mtcars, aes()) +
  geom_histogram(aes(y = after_stat(density)))


If I convert these to functions and supply the data, and press tab (autocomplete), it does not know to look in the supplied dataset:
hist_g <- function(df, variable) {
     ggplot(data = df, aes(!!ensym(variable))) +
      geom_histogram(aes(y = after_stat(density)))
}

hist_g(mtcars, )
# hist_g(mtcars, mpg)


sum_fun <- function(df, variable) {
    var <- enquo(variable)
    df %>%
      group_by(!!ensym(var)) %>%
      dplyr::summarize(freq = n())
}
sum_fun(mtcars, )
# sum_fun(mtcars, carb)


What do I need to do to the function to tell it to look in the dataset that is supplied?
thanks

As far as I know (and I have previously unsuccessfully asked for support from the RStudio team!) there is no way to add custom auto-complete logic. Support for functions from ‘dplyr’ and ‘ggplot2’ (etc.) is hard-coded into RStudio, alas.
